# implicit value of Function2 is not the same as implicit[Function2]

Tags: scala

I have the following two test cases:

TEST CASE 1：

```
  @Test
  def testImplicit1(): Unit = {
    class Person(val age: Int)
    val func: Person => Int = p => p.age
    implicit val x = func
    val y = implicitly((p: Person) => Int)
    println(func.hashCode())
    println(x.hashCode())
    println(y.hashCode())
  }
```

**x** and func have the same hashcode, while **y's** hashcode is different with the other two.

TEST CASE 2:

```
  @Test
  def testImplicit2(): Unit = {
    class Person(val age: Int)
    implicit val p = new Person(10)
    val p2 = implicitly[Person]
    println(p.hashCode())
    println(p2.hashCode())

  }
```

p and p2 have the same hash code

I would ask why y's hashcode is different with func and x's in TEST CASE 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`implicitly` is defined as:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

What you are doing in test case 1 is explicitly passing in the value (not the type) for argument e as `((p: Person) => Int)` which is a function that takes a `Person` as argument and returns the object `Int`. Then `implicitly` just returns that same value back to you.

What you want is:

```
val y = implicitly[Person => Int]
```

Which will cause the scala compiler to fill in the argument value e with your implicit value `x`.